# Alt+Tab en autohotkey

Tags: windows, script, autohotkey

He creado un script muy basico con autohotkey que desactiva la combinación de teclas alt+tab
El código es el siguiente:

```
; Disable Alt+Tab
!Tab::Return
```

El script funciona bien porque desactiva la combinación, el problema esque cuando esta en funcionamiento si apreto alt y luego tab, el tab ya no funciona y yo quiero que si lo haga, es decir, que funcionen las dos teclas pero sin hacer la combinación.

Si se apreta al revés primero tab y luego alt si funcionan los dos, pero alt y luego tab no.

Si alguien sabe como hacerlo y puede ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
; Deshabilite Alt Tab, pero aún presione Tab
!Tab::
Send {Alt Up}    ; "Levanta" la tecla Alt 
Send {Tab}       ; Usa la tecla Tab por sí mismo
Send {Alt Down}  ; "Presiona" la tecla Alt hacia abajo nuevamente
Return
```

Comment: Va muy bien, aunque no entiendo porque cuando aprietas varias teclas al mismo tiempo como puede ser por ejemplo que vas apretando en un juego la tecla w y el shift, si a la vez apretas alt y tab si que funciona la combinacion, no se porque puede ser, aunque me he dado cuenta que solo es si se apreta ctrl+alt+tab o shift+alt+tab, igualmente muchas gracias amigo. De todas formas almenos asi me va bien porque no suelo apretar tantas teclas a la vez, pero como me gusta buscar la perfeccion simplemente lo digo. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Puede bloquear las otras combinaciones de la misma forma que antes. Me alegro de haber podido ayudar.